# Make gnome-terminal request user confirmation before close

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, signal

When you open `gnome-terminal` without any options and execute a blocking command (e.g. `python3`, `vim` or `cat`) and then try to close the window by the close button (i.e. `x` button in the title bar) or some keyboard shortcut, a confirmation window is displayed:

[image]

However, when you open `gnome-terminal` with an executed command specified, that is, in the form of `gnome-terminal -- python3`, the confirmation window is no longer displayed and the window is closed right after you (accidentally) click the close button.

Is it possible to show the confirmation window even when you use the form `gnome-terminal -- <command>`? If that's impossible, is there any workarounds?

---

**Environments:**

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
# GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 using VTE 0.60.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD
```

**What I've Tried:**

- Equipping the executed command with signal handlers for [all the supported signals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17256355/8776746) didn't work; the window was still closed without confirmation although the process survived the closure while catching `SIGHUP` (three times), `SIGCONT` (once) and `SIGWINCH` (once). I had additionally to execute `kill -SIGKILL <process id>` to kill the process.
- I found one exception. When you execute `gnome-terminal -- bash`, the confirmation **is** displayed (though this is by default the same as `gnome-terminal`).

Comment: It is really great that MATE Terminal operates normally! You have to report (or find related) bug against GNOME Terminal on bugs.launchpad.net and maybe on GNOME GitLab.

Comment: Also python is not a "blocking" process. So it behaves as if you were running bash or another shell. It will, however, warn if some python script is actually running, just as when in bash, something is running.

Comment: @N0rbert Which version of `mate-terminal` are you using? My `MATE Terminal 1.24.0` shows the same behavior as `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNOME Terminal checks if there is foreground process started by shell (see [terminal_screen_has_foreground_process](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/db1ed76fef7c88d5f2e6547492a1265b9ab1dfcf/src/terminal-screen.c#L2203) function)

You can use sh to create new process and gnome-terminal to ask before exit this way:

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -i -c python3
```

Update:
The same effect may be achieved with bash using custom script:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -i my_script.sh
```

and the content of `my_script.sh` is just

```
python3
```

Comment: Worked on Linux Mint but didn't work on Arch Linux. (On Arch Linux, `sh` is a link to `bash` while it is a link to `dash` on Linux Mint. However, even after installing `dash` and specifying `dash` explicitly, the code didn't work on Arch Linux. Trying to find the cause...)

Comment: My gnome-terminal version is `# GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 using VTE 0.60.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD` from Ubuntu 20.04. I tried this method with bash, and it didn't work, that's why I used sh. With bash I managed to achieve the same effect only using custom script:
`gnome-terminal -- bash -i my_script.sh` and the content of my_script.sh is just `python3`

Comment: You are my hero. Please append the `my_script.sh` method in the answer? It worked like a charm.